# What is and how to open .mdl file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have some **.mdl** file on my PC. Can you tell me how to open it? What it is used for and is it supported in Matlab 2012? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .mdl file is a simulink model file. You can open it by typing *simulink* into the Command Window and then going to File -> Open

You can also just use the open command: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/open.html

Comment: But it is not supported anymore in Matlab 2012